# html - images and svg elements

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm working on an interactive map but can't put images on it.
The .svg map is developed on Inkscape, and is divided into districts.

I need to put images in these districts.

I wrote some code for this but it's only working in the Firefox browser. When i point with my mouse on this image the whole page starting to lag. In Opera and Chrome browsers this image is displayed in low resolution.

This part of the code from begining to this district on picture included:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="svg2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1771.6535
1771.6535" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1771.6535 1771.6535;" xml:space="preserve">
  
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img1" width="100" height="100" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <image xlink:href="./Regions/Arbuzinka.png" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="30%" height="30%" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  
  
  <a class="Arbuzinka" href="http://arbuzinkabib.tk">
    <g
      inkscape:groupmode="layer"
      id="layer18"
      inkscape:label="Арбузинка"
      style="display:inline"
      transform="translate(0,719.29131)">
      <path
        class="region"
        d="m 629.95741,-565.91816 -8.12988,-0.12207 -0.0732,5.44434 -6.5918,-0.19532
        -0.34179,8.44727 -4.68754,-0.0244 -0.1709,6.03027 -2.417,5.46875 1.001,10.4248
        1.3183,5.78614 2.6368,19.09179 -6.2989,3.24707 0.708,11.18164 -67.1374,30.41936
        -0.5006,20.95771 5.9731,2.90024 0.086,0.0345 -2.7967,12.74035 -11.1862,15.28424
        -3.1616,2.51465 -2.1179,3.76587 3.1298,3.97637 -2.2326,19.18647 8.5855,17.2133
        6.2925,6.95713 4.7647,3.50446 6.2972,0.34025 5.5664,9.79005 5.1514,13.35449
        3.7598,7.56836 1.1718,3.51562 3.125,3.90625 2.5391,4.29688 -0.1953,1.95312 -1.3672,3.32032 -1.1719,3.90625 -1.3672,2.73437 -2.539,2.92969 -1.7578,4.10156
        -0.586,1.95313 1.3672,1.75781 3.125,1.75781 2.5391,1.5625 2.9297,0.78125
        3.9062,0.58594 2.3438,0 3.7109,0.58594 2.3438,1.17187 3.3203,1.36719 3.5156,2.14844
        2.3437,1.75781 1.7579,0.68359 1.6601,1.85547 1.2695,0.68359 -0.3906,2.63672
        -0.5859,3.51563 -0.6836,1.36719 -0.293,2.14843 0.7813,1.17188 0.9765,1.75781
        2.5606,6.38337 0.6215,1.38107 0.6215,1.86444 0.2762,1.9335 c 0,0 0.2762,0.69053
        0.1381,0.96675 -0.1381,0.27621 -0.5524,1.93349 -0.5524,1.93349 l 0.069,1.31202
        -0.8977,1.86444 c 0,0 -0.1381,1.24296 -0.2071,1.58823 -0.069,0.34526 0.069,1.51917
        0.069,1.79538 0,0.27622 0.069,0.82864 0.069,1.24297 0,0.41432 -0.2072,1.86444
        -0.2072,1.86444 l -0.1192,2.92068 0.293,1.36719 -0.4883,1.75781 0,0.87891 0,1.46484
        0.293,1.07422 0.6836,0.78125 1.3672,1.36719 c 0,0 0.8789,1.17187 1.0742,1.5625
        0.1953,0.39062 0.7812,0.78125 0.8789,1.46484 0.098,0.6836 0.098,1.17188
        0.098,1.17188 0,0 0.098,0.19531 0.3906,0.78125 0.293,0.58593 0.6836,1.36718
        0.6836,1.36718 l 0.098,0.48829 8.00789,-1.07422 27.83203,-7.22657 -0.87891,-8.00781
        -2.24609,-8.10547 3.80859,-0.58593 -0.0977,-4.88282 5.95703,-2.24609 0.97656,-
        4.98047 2.24609,-2.05078 2.83204,3.61328 12.98828,29.88281 6.83593,-1.46484
        3.61329,-2.05078 20.50781,-3.71094 12.5,-3.71094 -1.75781,-16.11328 0.92773,-3.36914
        20.70313,-1.95312 1.31835,7.61718 1.98143,5.99878 6.90529,-0.38354 11.42578,-2.88086
        -3.72627,-19.28154 0.62148,-2.27876 6.90534,-1.0358 -3.93605,-25.3426 -1.45012,-
        3.79793 -1.24296,-2.20971 2.48592,-1.45012 8.15516,-1.29299 4.58985,-0.73243
        3.95508,-1.61132 0.73242,-1.07422 -0.87891,-5.07813 -2.24609,-7.91015 -16.37911,-
        67.99604 -1.79539,-7.18155 -5.52427,-24.72112 -1.51917,-2.34781 -0.7098,-4.19881
        -6.34765,0.14649 -1.07422,-1.12305 -1.31836,-11.18164 -7.66602,-2.7832 -3.18565,-
        15.6627 0.69053,-2.62403 5.38617,-0.13811 -5.52428,-45.16092 2.62403,0.27621
        0.82864,-0.82864 -1.60069,-14.76806 -4.29687,0.29297 0.39062,-18.65235 -3.22265,0
        -4.10157,9.66797 -7.74675,9.71784 -14.95832,1.8056 -8.1543,4.66308 -1.46484,-
        29.19921 -3.95508,-1.61133 -3.51563,0.75684 -32.32422,14.55077 -5.88379,1.00098
        -0.78125,-0.0732 -0.63476,-0.43946 -0.53711,-0.63476 -1.87988,-4.3457 1.66015,-
        2.70996 2.27051,0.39062 -4.69971,-19.86694 -2.47802,-3.32642 z"
        id="path3343"
        fill="url(#img1)"
        inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    </g>
  </a>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What do you mean "start to lag". Also what does "image is displayed in low resolution" mean exactly? It is pixellated?  Unfortunately we can't tell from your example snippet because the link to the image is broken.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau i mean its like droping fps in moment when i point my mouse on image. And in other browsers this image like in blur, but without fps dropping. Resolution of this image: 678x666

Comment: @Paulie_D its just a part of a code where i put image on this specific district, if needed i can copy/paste the whole code of map and make pictures of map, just can't paste pictures in this question without reputation.

Comment: @Paulie_D this part <defs>
    <pattern id="img1" width="100" height="100" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <image xlink:href="./Regions/Arbuzinka.png" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="30%" height="30%" />
    </pattern>
  </defs> and in path this line put it in district: fill="url(#img1)"